# macOS equivalent of the "where" command used in a Windows Command Prompt

Tags: terminal, command-line, search

In a Windows Command Prompt, I can find the location of things like Java and GIT by using the `where` command.

For example, typing `where java` yields `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05`.

What is the macOS Terminal equivalent for the Windows Command Prompt command, `where`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The macOS Terminal equivalent of the Windows Command Prompt command `where` is `which`.

Typing `which java` in my macOS Terminal yields `/usr/bin/java`, and `which git` yields `/usr/bin/git`.

Comment: Depending on the shell that you use then other shell builtin commands such as type, command, or whence could be used.

Answer (score 23):

The `which` command prints the most precedent application on the PATH whereas `where` prints all matching applications on the path.

The difference manifests when you have side by side instances of an application installed and all set on the path. Strictly speaking ***which*** by itself returns the instance resolved first on the path left to right, ***where*** returns ALL found instances on the path resolved left to right. If you want to see what I'm talking about, on a Windows 7 or above system type:

`where notepad` you may see two paths returned

```
C:\>where notepad 
C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe
C:\Windows\notepad.exe
```

The real equivalence is

`which -a someApp` === `where someApp`