# why can't i delete jdk11 in MacBook pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, java, android

I have nothing related to jdk11 in /library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines but still i see java version is 11 when i run java -versions .
Steps i tried

1. restarting mac
2. testing in new terminal after closing it .
3. Uninstalled java on mac by following official [link](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/mac_uninstall_java.html)

**My goal** is to setup jdk1.8 because jdk11 throwing multiple plugin and dependencies sync error with jdk11 when i create android project in android studio .

I am using jdk1.8 in android studio but mac java persist and override it with jdk11 when i launch "Java -version " in android studio terminal.

My environment :
MAc OS Big sur 11.5.2
MacBook Pro

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the `/Library` in the root directory - not the `Library` folder in your home directory?

Comment: Android Studio come with its own JRE, clould that be the issue ?? - have a look here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608742/how-to-set-java-sdk-path-in-androidstudio

Comment: And a JRE can't be used for compiling code.

Comment: Try [`which java`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/272717/95704) to locate the Java installation folder.

Comment: which java 
/usr/bin/java
but where is /usr/bin...
sorry for asking such a silly question 
my user is sX46TA

Comment: Also youy can have multiple versions of java installed so just install JDK 8 and alter the preferences in Android Studio to use that on - I suspect you can choose a different java for each project